# Ansi C - Convert String to Lower Case String

Tags: c, string, lowercase

I need to convert a char array to a lower case char array. I also want to convert some special characters like Ä to ä. But the "ASCII-Code" 196 isn't in the ASCII-128. How can I convert them to lower case ? I can use them as string initializer but can't really deal with their codes. In case this might be a compiler option I'm using eclipse CDT on Linux without c99 mode (can't use that one).

```
char* toLowerCase(char* text)
{
    int length = strlen(text);
    char* result = malloc(length); // malloc adds the 0 automatically at result[length]
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if ((text[i] >= 65) && (text[i] <= 90))
            result[i] = text[i] | 32;
        else
            result[i] = text[i];
    return result;
}

toLowerCase("hElLo WoRlD ÄäÖöÜü");
// result is "hello world ÄäÖöÜü"
```

`tolower()` from `ctype.h` doesn't do it either.

Comment: Apart from being utterly non-portable, this further extends the misery by being utterly non-high-asci friendly. And you can't use a compiler based on a standard thats *only* 14 years old? I bet your prof is *real* popular.

Comment: Your return string lacks termination.

Comment: Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) before you go any further dealing with characters.

Comment: @WhozCraig My prof was pretty popular. But that's not the point and I'm not a lazy student. Despite that I'm also unhappy about it I'm bound to this restrictions. I just solved it on my own anyways.

Comment: Excellent! "was" popular? I hope there isn't a sad end to that story. Anyway, very good for solving it. grats!

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes "was" because that was when I knew him. And now I'm just not in contact. I guess you're just a lazy student troll.

Comment: @mini-me Yeah, ok. So it goes. Everyone has two things; one of them is an opinion. Glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to read about [setlocale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale), ([or here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/))

and use tolower()

> **Notes:**   During program startup, the equivalent of setlocale(LC_ALL,
>   "C"); is executed before any user code is run.

You can try the Environment's default locale (or select the correct if you know it):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```